# Best answer contest: First quarter of 5777

Tags: discussion, status-completed, answer-contest

**The contest is over. Winners are announced [here](http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/4231/best-answer-contest-winners-first-quarter-of-5777).**

This post is locked to freeze the voting.

---

Did you see an answer on Mi Yodeya in the past few months that you thought was really great? Let's have a contest to help you tell everyone about it!

**Please link to an answer which was created in Tishrei - Kislev, 5777 (from October 3rd 2016 through December 29th 2016) and which you think deserves an additional reward. Only one entry per answer will be valid. For multiple favorites submit separate answers to this post.**

Here is a data query to help with the decision making process:

[Answers with most votes from 1st quarter of 5777](http://data.stackexchange.com/judaism/query/626662/answers-with-best-score-created-in-5777-q1?Count=50)

Otherwise you can chose your own favorite answer which didn't get the limelight or needed more appreciation. Answer can be from you or from someone else.

[image: 300-point Bounty button]

The answer linked in the highest voted answer to this meta post will receive a bounty of 300 points after completion of the event on February 17th, 2017. In case of a tie, the distinction will be shared, and the prize will be split.

---

<sup>Concept and words borrowed from [Movies.SE](https://movies.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2558/rewards-for-the-best-answer-from-the-4th-quarter-of-2016).</sup>

Comment: You are more than welcome to post and to vote on as many entries as you want. There will only be one winner, based on votes (unless there's a tie, in which case there will be co-winners). There may be runners-up. Every entry will get extra attention and result in more people learning more about Judaism, so we all win with each one.

Answer (score 4):

[Monica Cellio's answer](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/77037/2) to [How to suggest a kosher restaurant for a meeting?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/77034/how-to-suggest-a-kosher-restaurant-for-a-meeting) provides great experience- and sensitivity-based advice and manages to consider various possible scenarios while remaining concise.

Answer (score 4):

[Josh Waxman's answer](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/77235/472) to [What are the 10 utterances in Pirkei Avot 5:1](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/77231/what-are-the-10-utterances-in-pirkei-avot-51) answers the question with a (cited/linked) list of texts (not just citations of *p'sukim*), explains where sources disagree, and specifically addresses a suggestion in the question (that turned out not to be correct).  It also anticipates and briefly answers an objection that one might raise from the answer.

The question (at this writing) has had only 69 views.

Answer (score 3):

https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/78269 is directly relevant, from an authoritative source, and concise without being opaque; it quotes its source and translates it; and it provides a short summary of further relevant reading with a pointer thereto. All that's missing IMO is hyperlinks.

Answer (score 3):

[DoubleAA's thorough answer](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/77842/8775) documenting the censorship of the 12th blessing of the Amidah; particularly its first word.

Answer (score 3):

[My answer](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/77874/8775) to why periodic Torah reading is necessary as supplemental Torah study, given the necessity of daily reciting the Sh'ma.