# Best Answer Contest winners! First quarter of 5777

Tags: discussion, status-completed, answer-contest

Congratulations and *Yeyasher Kochachem* to the co-winners of the [Best Answer Contest  for the first quarter of 5777](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4218/best-answer-contest-first-quarter-of-5777)!

Here are the original citations, submitted by Monica Cellio and Isaac Moses, respectively:

- [Josh Waxman's answer](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/77235/472) to [What are the 10 utterances in Pirkei Avot 5:1](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/77231/what-are-the-10-utterances-in-pirkei-avot-51) answers the question with a (cited/linked) list of texts (not just citations of *p'sukim*), explains where sources disagree, and specifically addresses a suggestion in the question (that turned out not to be correct).  It also anticipates and briefly answers an objection that one might raise from the answer.
- [Monica Cellio's answer](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/77037/2) to [How to suggest a kosher restaurant for a meeting?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/77034/how-to-suggest-a-kosher-restaurant-for-a-meeting) provides great experience- and sensitivity-based advice and manages to consider various possible scenarios while remaining concise.

The winning entries will split the 300-point bounty prize evenly.

The Best Answer Contest for the second quarter of 5777, covering Tevet through Adar (Dec. 30, 2016 through Mar. 27, 2017) will take place after Passover. If you see a great answer between now and then, make a note of it! (Consider favoriting the question.) Yes, [Purim Torah](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/797/purim-torah-policy-allowed-but-regulated) answers will be eligible.

Comment: Thank you for your bounty donations and encouragement!