# Best answer contest: Second quarter of 5779

Tags: discussion, status-completed, answer-contest

Have you seen (or written) a recent answer on Mi Yodeya that you thought was really great? Let's have a contest to help you tell everyone about it!

This contest has two phases: Nomination and Voting. It is currently **over**. Read about the winners here: [Best Answer Contest winners! Second quarter of 5779](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5120/best-answer-contest-winners-second-quarter-of-5779)

1. **Nomination** - ending April 10, 2019

   Post an answer to this Meta post containing a link to the Mi Yodeya answer you want to nominate. Answers created in **Tevet - Adar II, 5779 (from December 9, 2018 through April 5, 2019)** are eligible<sup>1</sup>.

   Please link to one answer in each entry. Nominate as many answers as you like in separate answers to this post.

   *When you see a great answer, don't wait; post a link to it here before you forget!*

   Please *do not* vote on any answers to this post during the Nomination phase.
2. **Voting** - April 10 - 17, 2019

   On April 10, this post was edited to indicate that the Voting phase has begun, and the [featured](/questions/tagged/featured) tag was added.

   During this phase, everyone is invited to vote on the answers to this post however you see fit. Upvote (or downvote, I guess) as many as you like.

[image: 400-point bounty button]

The answer linked in the highest voted answer to this meta post will receive a bounty of 400 points<sup>2</sup> after completion of the event on April 17. 2019. In case of a tie, the distinction will be shared, and the prize will be split.

---

<sup>1. Yes, this does include [Purim Torah](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/797/purim-torah-policy-allowed-but-regulated) answers.</sup>

<sup>2. In honor of this "quarter" having been extended by the Sanhedrin of [Hillel Hakatan](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hillel_II) to four months.</sup>

<sup>Concept and words borrowed from [Movies.SE](https://movies.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2558/rewards-for-the-best-answer-from-the-4th-quarter-of-2016).</sup>

Comment: For beating out 4 months of answers shouldn't the prize become 400?

Comment: @DoubleAA Fine!

Comment: This took quite some time to research, not sure if it's worth nominating: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/100201/16354

Comment: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/100595/ptij-wiping-amalek-s-memory/100596#100596

Comment: Locked to end voting

Answer (score 7):

I would like to nominate [Alex's](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/users/13438/alex) [answer](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/98390/11501) to [How long was the period of Oppression](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/75610/11501) which, in a near-essay, brings together multiple historical sources, factoids and wonderful writing to answer an age-old question.

Answer (score 7):

I'd like to nominate [sam](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/users/1418/sam)'s [answer](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/99310/759) to [Is using hair removal cream on one's face a violation of "rounding one's beard?"](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/99303/759) A picture is worth a thousand words, and all the more when demonstrating historical positions. It's hard to imagine ever giving a Shiur on this topic again without showing off these photos of a rare artifact. Thank you sam!

Answer (score 6):

I would like to nominate [DonielF](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/users/9682/donielf)'s [answer](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/99739/11501) to [Does the Holy Ark weigh 4 tons?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/99733/11501) which demonstrates impressive, detailed and original research.

Answer (score 5):

I nominate [Micha Berger](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/98082/759)'s [answer](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/98082/759) to [When, halachically, does a sect of Judaism become an independent religion?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/98072/759) His thorough summary of a seminal article on the topic captures the nuance and complexity of the issue while remaining readable and succinct.

Answer (score 5):

[Yair Rand](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/users/18701/yair-rand)'s [answer](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/99429/759) to [what percentage of Reform Jews are halachically Jewish?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/4987/759) does original statistical analysis for a question that many Yodeyans had previously thought impossible to answer with firm basis. Thank you Yair for taking the time to bring that information to the community.

Answer (score 3):

mbloch's [answer](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/98226/2) to [Shabbat Amidah, which parts](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/98225/shabbat-amidah-which-parts) addresses a beginner-POV question that includes significant confusion about basic matters by carefully pulling apart all of the issues and addressing each one with links to authoritative, accessible resources. This is a great example of how to be as helpful as possible to someone who needs to start with the basics.

Answer (score 2):

I would like to nominate Dr. Shmuel’s [Maseches Yodeya](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/100253/). I flat-out don’t believe him in [how long it took to make this](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/100251/ptij-is-there-any-jewish-talmudic-literature-which-discusses-mi-yodeya-guidelin/100253#comment335089_100253); it’s very well put together, and he clearly took the time to research some MY lore in his discussions of site policy, the original Alex’s leaving, and much more.

Comment: Btw I see plenty of flaws with it however shkoyach

Comment: @Dr.Shmuel It’s not perfect, but it’s still a great post that gave me a good laugh.

Answer (score 1):

I nominate [kouty](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/users/9215/kouty)'s [answer](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/97904/1569) to [What should have Rabbi Tarfon done?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/83451/1569) for bringing relevant sources that explain Rabbi Tarfon's own practices in ruling and practicing like Beit Shamai and Beit Hilel.

Answer (score 1):

I would like to nominate [Meir](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/users/18471/meir)'s [answer](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/100354/16354) to my PTIJ question, [PTIJ: Aliyot for the deceased](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/100350/ptij-aliyot-for-the-deceased). It was the type of answer that makes you laugh out loud, but also kick yourself for not thinking of it...

Answer (score 1):

[This](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/99296/9215) answer despite is mine

יהללך זר ולא פיך

But

חביבין עלי

Because this is pshat Gemara Tosfot centered

Comment: There's never been an issue with self-nominating.

Comment: I didn't know, I see that robev voted his answer

Comment: https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/4581/ https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/4223/ https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/4663/ and many others.

Answer (score 0):

I would like to nominate [my](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/users/16354/%D7%A8%D7%91%D7%95%D7%AA-%D7%9E%D7%97%D7%A9%D7%91%D7%95%D7%AA) [answer](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/98674/16354) to [Why is kedusha only said during the day?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/98121/why-is-kedusha-only-said-during-the-day/98674#98674)

It was a thoroughly researched answer, which tackled a few different possible answers with fascinating sources.

Answer (score 0):

I would like to also nominate [my](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/users/16354/%D7%A8%D7%91%D7%95%D7%AA-%D7%9E%D7%97%D7%A9%D7%91%D7%95%D7%AA) [answer](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/99331/source-for-it-being-a-mitzvah-to-make-fun-of-avodah-zarah/99340#99340) to [Source for it being a mitzvah to make fun of Avodah Zarah?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/99331/source-for-it-being-a-mitzvah-to-make-fun-of-avodah-zarah)

It provided a clear answer to the question, but also summarized and added to the previous literature discussing it.

Comment: What was the conclusion? Is nomination during voting allowed?

Comment: @DonielF it ends at the end of today, according to the post

Comment: You read that as עד ועד בכלל?

Comment: Yup! (dead space)