# Whatever Happened to the Best Answer Contests?

Tags: discussion, answer-contest

As far as I can tell, there have been "Best Answer Contests" from the first quarter of 5777 ([here](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4218/best-answer-contest-first-quarter-of-5777)) through the second quarter of 5780 ([here](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5283/best-answer-contest-second-quarter-of-5780)). As evidenced by the comments, nominations and votes at the last one, it appears that participation was way down. Since then, there have been no "Best Answer Contests".

1. Why have they ceased, and was there some sort of formal discussion that caused that?
2. Would people be interested in having one for the first quarter of 5781 (only slightly late)? I'd be happy to offer the bounty from my rep, if someone else can do the posting (just because my schedule and MY access is too unpredictable these days).

Comment: https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5283/best-answer-contest-second-quarter-of-5780?noredirect=1&lq=1#comment16767_5283

Comment: @Alex I saw that; but things like that have happened before.

Comment: If participation was down, you could consider changing from quarters to halves to make sure there are enough suggestions for nominations. Or any other rule variation as you see fit.

Comment: I suppose it's a symptom of a decreased activity, and we should try to find ways to improve that. If we could find a solution, the contest wouldn't be an issue either.

Comment: Whilst I appreciate that a lot of the old-timers have either stopped or moved on - are there not many new users that have joined since? I have been a member only for 8 months but during this time I have seen a number of new regulars emerge?

Comment: I, for one, definitely enjoyed the contests and would be happy to see them return (whether as before or in modified form).

Comment: The people demand glory! Kidding aside, I think it's a good idea. Who knows, it might even ignite some more interest in the site.

Answer (score 4):

1. I was running the contests, and I stopped doing it. There was no formal discussion precipitating this, nor a clear decision-making process on my part. Reduced participation was a factor, but certainly not the only factor.
2. Anyone who wants to run this or any similar community-building initiative, please go for it! There's very little in the way of moderator power required to run these things. If you do need a moderator to do certain tasks to make your initiative work, like locking posts on request, I'd be happy to assist, within the bounds of reasonableness.